# Karate : Dynamically input values from embedded expressions in a JSON file

Tags: karate

```
 * def mpRequestJson =
        """
        {
            "entity": '<entity>',
            "consent": {
                "PHONE": <updategetPhonePref>,
                "EMAIL": true,
                "POST": false,
                "SMS": <updategetSMSPref>
            },
            "notices": [{
                "title": "Privacy policy",
                "version": "NA"
            }],
            "source": "web"
        }
        """
        Given path '<entity>'
        And request mpRequestJson
        When method PUT
        Then status 200
        And match $.consent.PHONE == '<updategetPhonePref>'
        And match $.consent.SMS == '<updategetSMSPref>'

        Examples:
            |entity  | updategetPhonePref|updategetSMSPref|
            |xyz| #(updategetPhonePref)|#(updategetSMSPref)|
```

If i want to store the JSON request in a JSON file rather than in the feature file, what should be my JSON file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the JSON use [embedded expressions](https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions), e.g.

```
entity: '#(entity)'
```

Then you can read it from a file:

```
* def mpRequestJson = read('my.json')
```

But before the `read` you should initialize variables that have to be substituted. So you will have some extra lines.

```
* def entity = '<entity>'
```

One way to reduce the extra lines is to create a temp JSON:

```
* def data = { entity: '<entity'>, phone: '<updategetPhonePref>' }
```

And then you can do this in the JSON:

```
entity: '#(data.entity)'
```

Read the docs on [data driven tests](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests) also please.

Comment: Works perfectly fine. Only one change is as below def data = { entity: '<entity'>, phone: <updategetPhonePref>}. Since updategetPhonePref is already an embedded expression. Thanks for giving us the magic using Karate DSL [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/143475/peter-thomas)