# How to define request template in Background

Tags: karate

I have a request template that is used across multiple scenario outlines, and examples in each scenario outline differs.

for ex: 
Scenario Outline: 1 
* def query = { name: <name>} 
---do something else--- 
Examples: 
|name| 
|bob| 
|ram| 
 
Scenario Outline: 2 
* def query = { name:<name>} 
---do something else--- 
Examples: 
|name| 
|eve| 
 
How can I avoid duplicating query definition in each scenario outline? Defining it in background and reusing it in outline request is not dynamically building the request from the values in examples.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think you may be over-engineering things. Some amount of duplication is OK for tests - especially where it improves readability. Also see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54126724/143475

That said - you can switch to a [loop data-driven style](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features) like this:

```
Scenario Outline: 1 
* table data = 
| name  |
| 'bob' |
| 'ram' |
* call read('second.feature') data
```

And in `second.feature` you can do this:

```
* def query = { name: '#(name)' }
```

If you want to avoid the second feature file, the only other option is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55192450/143475